# iPhone app not working properly in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

Anybody have problem with their existing app not working in the iPad simulator?

I have a iPhone app which is a navigation-based app with tab bar and multiple tableviews -- and none of the table is showing up.

Basically, what is expected -- a long rows of table. In iPad, nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you can point to specific items which aren't working it might help in this case.  I think your question is to broad.  Is anything working at all for the iPad version of the app just perhaps oriented strangely?

How did you upgrade your iPhone app to iPad?  Did you use the "Upgrade target to iPad" feature built into XCode or did you create a new project file altogether?  Some other method?

Comment: It looks like my tableview has no data to load. Well, iPhone app should be able to just work in ipad, so I ran my current app in the iPad simulator. 

I did try to set the base SDK to 3.2 and target at 3.1 -- still not working for me.